# QML Dialog with focused textField

Tags: dialog, focus, qml, textfield, qt-quick

I am working on Qt quick application and I wanna open dialog. In this dialog window is `TextField` and I want to set focus to this `textField` after `dialog` is open.
This code doesn't work.

```
function newFolder() {
    newFolderDialog.visible = true
    newFolderDialog.open()
}

Dialog {
    id: newFolderDialog
    title: "New folder"
    height: 150
    width: 300
    standardButtons: StandardButton.Ok | StandardButton.Cancel

    Column {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Text {
            text: "Name"
            height: 40
        }
        TextField {
            id: newFolderInput
            width: parent.width * 0.75
            focus: true
            onFocusChanged: console.log("Focus changed " + focus)
        }
    }

    onVisibilityChanged: {
        if(visible === true){
            newFolderInput.text = ""
            newFolderInput.focus = true
        }

    }
}
```

output to console is:

> qml: Focus changed false
> qml: Focus changed true
> qml: Focus changed false

It look like, that somehow focus is changed after I set focus to `textField`

Comment: This works for me in Qt 5.5. The focus goes to the TextField and there are four lines in the console (false, true, false, true).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need the function as it is written. From the docs of `Dialog` for the function `open()`:

> Shows the dialog to the user. It is **equivalent to setting visible** to true.

Given that (it's not the problem) it seems like the focus is continously contended between the dialog and the contained element. The more you open/close the `Dialog`, the more evaluations occurs. I cannot figure out why this happens, right now. However, you can easily solve the problem by (1) getting rid of `onVisibilityChanged` handler and (2) rewriting `newFolder()`. Final code rewritten:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    width: 360
    height: 300
    visible: true

    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "click me!"
        onClicked: newFolder()
    }

    Dialog {
        id: newFolderDialog
        title: "New folder"
        height: 150
        width: 300
        standardButtons: StandardButton.Ok | StandardButton.Cancel
        focus: true    // Needed in 5.9+ or this code is NOT going to work!! 

        Column {
            anchors.fill: parent
            Text {
                text: "Name"
                height: 40
            }
            TextField {
                id: newFolderInput
                width: parent.width * 0.75
                focus: true
                onFocusChanged: console.log("Focus changed " + focus)
            }
        }
    }

    function newFolder() {
        newFolderDialog.open()
        newFolderInput.focus = true
    }
}
```

This way you first open the dialog and then set the focus to the proper `Item`.

Comment: Your solution didnt help. It show dialog correctly but not add focus to textField

Comment: It works for me, on 5.3 and 5.4. I've edited with my full test code (which is your code plus a button...). Maybe there's something about your setting which is missing?

Comment: Yes it work! My bad was, that i wrote `newFolderInput.visible = true` instead of `newFolderInput.focus = true` Thank you a lot!

Comment: In **QT 5.9** above solution works only if the `focus` is set to `true` in the dialog initialization.  `Dialog{focus : true}`

Comment: @pra7 I guess they solved some sort of bug inside dialog? They are more or less discontinued in favour of QC2 and platform lab controls. It's a long time since the last time I've used the dialogs libs. I'm going to add the line of code, thanks for pointing that out. :)

Answer (score 3):

I had to use [forceActiveFocus()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#forceActiveFocus-method) method after opening the dialog

```
onClicked: {
    dialog.open()
    input.forceActiveFocus()
}
```